# Given an N-Dimensional point P, is each component P(c) = 0 for c > N or is P(c) undefined?

Tags: geometry

A concrete example:

Given a 2D point P with coordinates (x,y), if it were looked at from a 3D perspective would it have coordinates (x,y,0)?

This seems to be a common assumption but I have yet to find anything that clearly states it. I understand that all 2D points can exist on some arbitrary XY plane; is it just a convention that the XY plane happens to be z=0?

Comment: Yes, because this is the simplest possible choice of planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in which to embed the $xy$ plane.  Sometimes I do this when I teach Green's Theorem or I want to find the area of a parallelogram in the $xy$ plane and I want to take the "cross product" of two two-dimensional vectors.